# ¿por que java script no me realiza las sumas?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo el siuiente script quiero hacer una especia de eccomerce pero el script de sumas mediante js no me anda dejo mi codigo aqui a un lado

```
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="a" id="Ra" >Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="1" name="a" id="Ra" checked>Valor 1</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="b" id="Rb" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="2" name="b" id="Rb">Valor 2</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="c" id="Rc" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="3" name="c" id="Rc">Valor 3</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="d" id="Rd" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="4" name="d" id="Rd">Valor 4</div><br/>

<div id="sumando"></div>
<script>
function sumar() {
   var a,b,c,d,sumatorio,text;  
   a = document.getElementById("Ra").value;  
   b = document.getElementById("Rb").value;  
   c = document.getElementById("Rc").value;  
   d = document.getElementById("Rd").value;  
   if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c) || isNaN(d)) {  
     texto = "Es necesarios introducir dos números válidos";  
   } else {  
     //si no ponemos parseFloat concatenaría x con y  
     sumatorio=parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)+parseFloat(c)+parseFloat(d);  //suma=parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y); 
     texto= sumatorio;  
   }  
document.getElementById("sumando").innerHTML = texto;
//alert("4 + 10 = "+ suma(4, 10) ); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pista, los identificadores deben ser **únicos**.

Comment: No te preocupes, ando armando una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias hermano. ando algo extresado tuve que dormir un rato para aliviar el dolor de cabeza es que quiero implementar eso en pympay.com en los estreamin se que los id deben ser unicos pero no se me ocurre nada si no un select y no quiero poner select

Comment: Gracias Hermanito agradecido de verdad bendiciones

Comment: Recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió dándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.

Comment: intento agregar otro valor la misma pregunta jajajaj no me sale creo que sigo en la misma

Comment: La pregunta esta esta bien en la suma pero mal para lo que necesito en realidad vi 2 errores asi que la hare de nuevo por que no consigo resolver el problema.

Comment: ok amigo, cualquier otra duda que tengas, puedes hacerlo en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema son tus identificadores, deben ser **únicos**.

---

Vamos a cambiar tus identificadores para que cada uno sean distintos:

```
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="a" id="Ra0" >Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="1" name="a" id="Ra1" checked>Valor 1</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="b" id="Rb0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="2" name="b" id="Rb2">Valor 2</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="c" id="Rc0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="3" name="c" id="Rc3">Valor 3</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="d" id="Rd0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="4" name="d" id="Rd4">Valor 4</div><br/>
```

Ahora faltaría obtener el valor de cada uno de ellos, podemos utilizar ternarios para no hacer extenso el código:

```
a = !document.getElementById("Ra0").checked ? document.getElementById("Ra1").value : 0;
b = !document.getElementById("Rb0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rb2").value : 0;
c = !document.getElementById("Rc0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rc3").value : 0;
d = !document.getElementById("Rd0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rd4").value : 0;
```

Para que entiendas mejor, recuerda que la estructura de un ternario vendría a ser la siguiente sintaxis:

```
condición ? valor_si_verdadero : valor_si_falso
```

Entonces, aquí indico que si los id (que su valor es 0) **no** están seleccionados, obtengo el valor de los id `Ra1`, `Rb2`, `Rc3` y `Rd4` (que los valores de estos no son 0, fijate en los `value` de cada uno de ellos), de lo contrario, el valor será 0. Estos valores serán asignados a tus variables `a`, `b`, `c` y `d`.

Y con esto ya lo tendrías. Código completo:

```js
function sumar() {
   var a,b,c,d,sumatorio,text;  
   a = !document.getElementById("Ra0").checked ? document.getElementById("Ra1").value : 0;  
   b = !document.getElementById("Rb0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rb2").value : 0;  
   c = !document.getElementById("Rc0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rc3").value : 0;  
   d = !document.getElementById("Rd0").checked ? document.getElementById("Rd4").value : 0;  
  
  // console.log(a, b, c, d);
  
   if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c) || isNaN(d)) {  
     texto = "Es necesarios introducir dos números válidos";  
   } else {  
     //si no ponemos parseFloat concatenaría x con y  
     sumatorio=parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)+parseFloat(c)+parseFloat(d);  //suma=parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y); 
     texto= sumatorio;  
   }  
document.getElementById("sumando").innerHTML = texto;
//alert("4 + 10 = "+ suma(4, 10) ); 
}
```

```html
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="a" id="Ra0" >Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="1" name="a" id="Ra1" checked>Valor 1</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="b" id="Rb0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="2" name="b" id="Rb2">Valor 2</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="c" id="Rc0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="3" name="c" id="Rc3">Valor 3</div><br/>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="0" name="d" id="Rd0" checked>Valor 0</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="sumar();" value="4" name="d" id="Rd4">Valor 4</div><br/>

<div id="sumando"></div>
```